# Unable to bring opened form to front/focus vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Hi i have five forms and i want to open a form only if it's not open, if it's open bring to front or focus. i have tried using `BringToFront`,`Show` and `TopMost` but nothing works.

```
If Not Application.OpenForms.OfType(Of StudentRegistrationFrm).Any Then
        StudentRegistrationFrm.ShowDialog()
    Else
        StudentRegistrationFrm.BringToFront()
        'Me.SendToBack()
End If
```

Comment: once you are done with StudentRegistrationFrm how to you remove it from view?

Comment: @Plutonix goes to the back.

Comment: Dialogs do not go to the back, so please show that code

Comment: @Plutonix `StudentRegistrationFrm` is the main form, user clicks on the menu strip to open a new form and from that form the user can click to open `StudentRegistrationFrm` again.

Comment: So is this: `StudentRegistrationFrm.ShowDialog()` trying to show another copy of the main form in Dialog fashion?  When you are done with a Dialog they are usually closed or hidden.  It cant go to the back.

Comment: I'm trying to bring it to front.

Comment: It really sounds like you should be using [MDI](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=multiple+document+interface&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8#safe=off&rls=en&q=multiple+document+interface+c%23) instead of SDI

Comment: If you are against the MDI idea, then you should read the documentation for `Form.ShowDialog` - it doesn't do what you want.  Read up on `Form.Show` also.

Comment: Yes.  Form.Show instead of Form.ShowDialog   Then start having fun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by closing the current form.

```
 If Not Application.OpenForms.OfType(Of StudentRegistrationFrm).Any Then
        StudentRegistrationFrm.Show()
    Else
        Me.Close()
    End If
   Private Sub StudentInformationToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles StudentInformationToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim studentReg As StudentInfoFrm = New StudentInfoFrm
    studentReg.Show()
    Me.Close()
 End Sub
```